# It's possible to reset poll watermark stored?

Tags: mule, esb, anypoint-studio

I would like to know how to reset poll watermark stored in Mule.

Is there any form?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I guess you mean how to clear it in Anypoint Studio?

Go to Run Configurations,

Select your application and change the setting at 'Clear Application Data' to 'Prompt'.

From now on for that application you will be asked if you want to keep or clear the data.

Comment: Ok, for while I need on Studio. But in production ESB runtime, what would be the way?

Comment: Have a look at the docs to get more info on how it's working behind the scenes: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/poll-reference#sts=Polling for Updates using Watermarks  you will need to use the clear the variable that it's hold in the Objectstore

Comment: Its not working for me. still not getting data its showing as  Watermark value will not be updated since poll processor returned no results on console

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to delete the folder with project name on .mule\.mule\project_name folder. Works well.

Comment: This worked for me as well - The path in my Anypoint workspace dir for my project was <Root>\anypoint-workspace\.mule\.mule\<projectName>\objectst‌​ore . The object store name is a long alpha-numeric string, I deleted it & on the next run of MuleSoft the Watermark was reset to the initial value (to 0 in my case)